# Как рисовать большое количество объектов одинаковой геометрии?

Tags: directx, шейдеры, hlsl

Если делать все операции над матрицами объектов используя ЦП, вершинный шейдер может возвращать просто позицию вершины, верно?

Теперь я хочу производить все трансформации( в том числе просто умножения матрицы объекта на матрицу камеры и проекции), используя видеокарту, то есть шейдер.

Это значит что в `Update()` я должен для каждого объекта вызывать `memcpy()` передавая пустой `constant buffer`? Или вообще не вызывать `memcpy`?

---

**Обновление**

[Тут мне уже уже немного объяснили](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/181228/138126)

Как я сейчас понимаю:

Создаю constant buffer, в который помещаю данные каждой вершины. В вершинном шейдере я могу обратиться к constant buffer вот так:

```
      cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register(b0)
       {
       //Элементы
       }
```

Я хочу просто отображать **много** кубов с возможностью перемещения. Сейчас я делаю все трансформации с матрицами с помощью ЦП и при 10к кубов лагает(пару фпс). Я думал передать в constant buffer ViewMatrix и ProjectionMatrix, а в качестве аргумента в функцию шейдера передавать координату вершины, и там всё перемножать.

**Я не понимаю как передавать координату вершины в качестве аргумента функции шейдера**. Насколько я понимаю, по умолчанию туда всегда передаётся то ли 0 то ли все 1(координаты вершины). Как раз для этого(если я понял правильно), нужен InstanceBuffer, в придачу к ConstantBuffer(но в это я пока не въехал).

Текущая проблема:

Сейчас мой ConstantBuffer это

```
cbuffer ConstantBuffer : register(b0)
{
float4x4 viewMat;
float4x4 projMat;
float4x4 posMat;
}
```

А функция шейдера

```
VS_OUTPUT main(VS_INPUT input)
{
VS_OUTPUT output;
output.pos=mul(input.pos,mul(posMat,mul(viewMat,projMat)));
output.color=input.color;
return output;
}
```

Где `VS_INPUT` И `VS_OUTPUT` содержат два `float4` позиции и цвета.

И проблема в том что ничего не рисуется. Сейчас пытаюсь решить это.

Вопрос: как эффективно рисовать большое количество объектов одинаковой геометрии используя шейдеры?

Comment: Не очень понятно, что вы там делаете, но обычно у объектов не должно быть собственного constant buffer.

Comment: @user7860670 вот я уже немного продвинулся в этом вопросе https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/181228/138126